# How to find an object by value in a multi level json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cypress

I have a json array, where I would like to find an item name and get the itemcat returned in javascript.

```
    "Allitems":[
      {"item":["APPLE IPHONE 13 PRO 256GB"], "itemcat": "Preorder"},
      {"item":["Samsung Galaxy S9+ 64GB","Samsung Galaxy S22", "Apple iPhone XR 256GB"], "itemcat": "Phones"}
]
```

currently I read the value that I want to search from a website using cypress

```
      cy.get(`.basket-body > :nth-child(${p}) > :nth-child(1) > > :nth-child(1) > `)
                            .invoke('text')
                            .then(text => {
                                cy.wait(600)
                                cy.log(text)
```

How could I pass (text) through a find function to get the corresponding itemcat value returned.
as the second item has more then 1 value that it should match search.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to  match by `text` as the item?

```js
var obj = {
  "Allitems": [{
      "item": ["APPLE IPHONE 13 PRO 256GB"],
      "itemcat": "Preorder"
    },
    {
      "item": ["Samsung Galaxy S9+ 64GB", "Samsung Galaxy S22", "Apple iPhone XR 256GB"],
      "itemcat": "Phones"
    }
  ]
}
var text = "Samsung Galaxy S22 is bla bla";

function find_cat(text, obj) {
  var cat = obj.Allitems.find(function(sub) {
    return sub.item.find(function(item) {
        return text.indexOf(item)>=0
    })
  })
  return (cat ? cat.itemcat : null)
}


console.log(find_cat(text, obj))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much, is there a way to adapt the function to check using contains, Text= "Samsung Galaxy S22 5G 128GB (Phantom Black)" but the array value is only Samsung Galaxy S22. So currently this returns null but as value contains text could we still pass this as true and return the itemcat? Thanks